# Stroke Box Around Text On a Path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new to illustrator and I am trying to replicate a t-shirt design. I have create a circle path, and have created text along the path. How do I create a "rounded rectangle" that fits around the text, the follows the curve of the path?

Here is the design I am trying to replicate

[image]

Here is what I have so far

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Illustrator click and hold the rectangle tool, then select the rounded rectangle tool. Draw a rectangle wide and low, then choose the stroke color and weight (line thickness).

Delete True Elite Fitness on the document and type it inside the rectangle. You can resize the rectangle to fit the text or vice-versa.
After that select both elements (rectangle and text) and use the alignment controls on the control panel (the bar under the menus) to align the text at the center of the rectangle.

Check that the rectangle and the text are selected and go to Object menu > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp. This opens the Warp Options window. In Style select Arc, then click Horizontal. Tick the Preview box on the bottom left of the window and drag the Bend slider to the left until you think it fits, then click OK. In case you can resize each element until everything is in place.